# Laravel One to one relasionship showing property non object

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent-relationship

I am trying basic laravel one to one relationship but there is an error.
 I have a table called posts(i will attach the image) and a Model Post.php. When I am trying to get the result from Route.php it is showing an error.[MySql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PhYM.png)[image: Error message]
User.php

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Post');
}
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('/user/post', function () {
 $post = User::find(1)->post;
return $post;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your routes as per below to work:

```
Route::get('/user/post', function () {
 $user = User::with('post)->where('id', 1)->get();
 return $user->post;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you insert your user model in the route.php correctly? if so, make sure to use protected $fillable =[] in your models. your route and relation both looked fine, the problem must be somewhere else like your models.